# UWP: How to make the ContentPresenter's FontWeight persist when corresponding radio button is pressed?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a radio button which when pressed should highlight the corresponding text. My code is as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle1" TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonForeground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,6,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-7,-3,-7,-3"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseStrokePointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseFillPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedStrokePointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedFillPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphFillPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphStrokePointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseStrokePressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseFillPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedStrokePressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedFillPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphFillPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphStrokePressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseStrokeDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseFillDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedStrokeDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedFillDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphFillDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphStrokeDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                           **<Ellipse x:Name="OuterEllipse" Fill="{StaticResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseFill}" Height="19.5" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Stroke="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseStroke}" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="19.5"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="CheckOuterEllipse" Fill="white" Height="19.5" Opacity="0" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Stroke="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedStroke}" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="19.5"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="CheckGlyph" Fill="Black" Height="13.5" Opacity="0" Stroke="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphStroke}" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="13.5"/>**
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


<RadioButtons>
   <RadioButton 
        Style ="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle1}"
        Content = "A"/>
   <RadioButton 
        Style ="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle1}"
        Content = "B"/>
</RadioButtons>
```

i tried adding the below lines to the template to make the content bold when selected.

```
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName ="ContentPresenter" 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontWeight">
   <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Bold"/>
 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Under visual state =Pressed but the content is bold only for a brief second. I would like the selected content to appear bold until deselected .How do I make this persist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Under visual state =Pressed but the content is bold only for a brief second. I would like the selected content to appear bold until deselected .How do I make this persist?

The problem is [`Pressed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstate?view=winrt-19041#examples) state only signify pressed time, if you would like the selected content to appear bold until deselected, please place your `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` into `Checked` VisualState.

```
<VisualState x:Name="Checked">
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            To="1"
            Duration="0" />
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            To="0"
            Duration="0" />
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            To="1"
            Duration="0" />
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontWeight">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Bold" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```